# Creating a new form - Sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list, custom-formatting

So I have the code as such:

```
    private void newAddFormForMembers(SPList list, SPWeb web)
    {
        list = web.Lists["MemberRecords"];
        string url = string.Format("_layouts/createform.apsx", web.ServerRelativeUrl, list.RootFolder.Url);

        var form = web.GetFile(url);
        if (form != null)
        {
            list.DefaultNewFormUrl = url;
            list.Update();
        }
    }
```

I have used SharePoint 2010 designer to go and grab the existing html for the creatform form when adding items to a particular list. I added in two new fields, first and last name. The list contains a member name, I removed this field from the create form because:

When I hit submit to add the item to the list, first and last name need to format them selves into "lastname, first name". Now I could submit the form back to my self - **How do I do that?** - and then do my string manipulation **How do i get the values form a field?** - and then push the information to the list **How do I do that?** but then I have anew issue

Edit will look the exact same as add, first and last name fields, how would I take the information from the list and populate the new edit form, particularly first and last name fields, keeping in mind that in the list they are in the format of "lastname, firstname"?

**This is all being done programatically**

Answer (score -1):

Instead of change html newForm for the list try to write an [Event Receiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg749858%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Instead of delete field from the newForm try to hide columns (You can do that programmatically or using external tool such as [Sharepoint Manager](http://spm.codeplex.com/)

Adding fields to the new/edit form and grab value on postback event I think is not simple/possible (via javascript you can access onPreSave where you can manipulate item values before postback, here you can write some jscript for save values into field but on edit is hard to split values).
You can: create two column on your list FirstName and LastName, plus a third field FullName (hidden for new/edit form) and with an EH on Added/Updated you can write FullName = LastName + ", " + FirstName or without EH you can create a calculated Field.

Comment: I am using an event receiver to create the new add and edit page. I fail to see how I could use an even receiver to add new fields to a edit or add form, process the data, spit it to the list, grab it from the list put it in edit and the spit it back out in the specified format - all in a single event receiver - if you have more resources please consider updating your post. downgraded for lack of clarity. @Max - Also this must be 100% programtically.

Comment: Have you see my changes on answer ?